# Spring Boot 3 security cannot access H2 console - 403

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, h2

I'm in the process of re-learning Spring security in Spring Boot 3.  Things changed a little and for some reason the same settings working for WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter's config method will not work in SecurityFilterChain.

HERE IS SOME CODE FROM PREVIOUS SETUPS- WORKING

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    private final AppUserService userService;
    private final PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public SecurityConfig(AppUserService userService, PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    private static final String[] SWAGGER = {
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/swagger-resources",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/webjars/**",
            "/v3/api-docs/**",
            "/swagger-ui/**"
    };


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors(c -> {
            CorsConfigurationSource cs = request -> {
                CorsConfiguration cc = new CorsConfiguration();
                cc.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
                cc.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
                cc.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Origin", "Content-Type", "X-Auth-Token", "Access-Control-Expose-Header",
                        "Authorization"));
                cc.addExposedHeader("Authorization");
                cc.addExposedHeader("User-Name");
                return cc;
            };
            c.configurationSource(cs);
        });
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(SWAGGER).permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users/password-reset-request").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users/password-change").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/favorites/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(GET).hasAnyAuthority("USER");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(POST).hasAnyAuthority("USER");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(PUT).hasAnyAuthority("USER");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(DELETE).hasAnyAuthority("MODERATOR");
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()));
        http.addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return userService;
    }
}
```

NOW SINCE

```
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

is no longer available:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS);
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Long story short- previously working

```
http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll();
```

Will not work as

```
http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll();
```

Application.properties for H2 database are exact same, copied. I didn't changed default url for H2. It seems its the Spring Security standing in the way.
Please advice what to do.

Do you have any knowlage if anything changed for H2 setup since previous Spring Boot?

EDIT: If I simply `http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();`, the console will work. It must be security related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration` will register](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/h2/H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.java) a `Servlet` for H2's Web Console, therefore, the `servletPath` property is needed in order to use the `MvcRequestMatcher`, like so:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) {
    // ...
    MvcRequestMatcher h2RequestMatcher = new MvcRequestMatcher(introspector, "/**");
    h2RequestMatcher.setServletPath("/h2-console");
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
        .requestMatchers(h2RequestMatcher).permitAll()
        // ...
    );
}
```

In summary, we are permitting every (`/**`) request under the `h2-console` servlet path.

Another option is to use `PathRequest.toH2Console()` as shown in the [Spring Boot H2 Console's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/data.html#data.sql.h2-web-console.spring-security), which in turn will create an `AntPathRequestMatcher` for you.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) {
    // ...
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
        .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toH2Console()).permitAll()
        // ...
    );
}
```

This problem has also been [answered](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12310#issuecomment-1328990026) in the project's repository

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been looking for this solution!

Answer (score 0):

in accordance to [spring-boot reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/data.html#data.sql.h2-web-console.spring-security) `SecurityFilterChain` bean may look like this:

```java
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> 
                        authorize
                                .requestMatchers(toH2Console()).permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
                .headers((headers) -> headers.frameOptions((frame) -> frame.sameOrigin()))
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
```